# Creating a user with POST , but it's not working correctly

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm creating a new user with `POST` and the program tells me it's created correctly , but when I check with `GET` if the user was created , it creates an empty `{}` entry. What can be wrong here?

```
app.get(BASE_API_PATH + "/contacts", (req, res) => {
    console.log(Date() + " - GET /contacts");

    db.find({}).toArray((err, contacts) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error accesing DB");
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }

        res.send(contacts.map((c) => {
            delete c._id;
            return c;
        }));
    });

});

app.post(BASE_API_PATH + "/contacts", (req, res) => {
    console.log(Date() + " - POST /contacts");
    var contact = req.body;


    if (!contact) {
        console.log("warning : new Get req");
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    db.find({ "name": contact.name }).toArray((err, contacts) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error accesing db");
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        if (contacts.length > 0) {
            console.log("warning");
            res.sendStatus(409);
        }
        else {
            db.insert(contact);
            res.sendStatus(201);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check in the db uf the user is well inserted ?

Comment: Can you access your mongodb with an application like https://robomongo.org/ ? Then you could debug the database. Maybe it's not created.

Comment: i created the db in mlabs , and when i create user only show this(dont create name,phone..only id) :

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ac7406463a50f2c03aaffdc"
    }
}

Comment: where you are getting `{}`, exactly at which line of code?

Comment: Dont know im checking with POSTMAN program

Comment: you are not mentioning `collection` in your queries ? I don't think if it is even saving in first place